# Mobx4 - observable.map .keys() .values() return function instead of array

Tags: javascript, mobx

I am trying to declare an observable.map using the decorate syntax.

```
class UiStore {
   loaders = observable.map({})
}

export default decorate(UiStore, {
   loaders: observable
})
```

But when I try to use `loaders.keys()` it just outputs the function definition, instead of returning a value:

> {next: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating  an observable from an observable.

```
class UiStore {
   loaders = observable.map({}) // Creates an observable map
}

export default decorate(UiStore, {
   loaders: observable // creates an observable from the observable map
})
```

It is enough to do it once (but not the problem here). Your main problem is, that you are expecting the wrong thing. Most map methods return an iterator and not an array as you expect. So your problem has nothing to do with mobx but with your understanding how javascript's Map methods work.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys

HowTo iterate over an interator

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

```js
const { decorate, observable, autorun } = mobx;

class UiStore {
   loaders = new Map()
}

const decoratedUiStore = decorate(UiStore, {
   loaders: observable
});

const uiStore = new decoratedUiStore();

autorun(() => {
  for (const key of uiStore.loaders.keys()) {
    console.log(key);
  }
});


uiStore.loaders.set('name', 'jeff');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mobx/4.1.1/mobx.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The thing is that according to the mobx documentation (https://mobx.js.org/refguide/map.html) the `.keys()` method should return an array of all the keys in the observable.map

Comment: Seems it changed with Mobx4, now we should use something like `Array.from(map.keys())` - which is basically the same as your anwser

Comment: No it doesn't state that. It says that they behave according to the ES6 Map spec: "The following methods are exposed according to the ES6 Map spec:"